# What is the difference between "What good is it to believe something" and "How good is it to believe something"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

The question is self-explanatory. I try to figure out the right choice between the two.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out x. versus I try to figure x out everyday. what and how do not mean the same thing....

Answer (score 2):

*What good is (something)?* means "what use is it?" or "What value does it have?", and is usually a dismissive question that implies "I don't think that it has any value". It often has a combative edge, implying "and I'm challenging you to prove me wrong!" If the speaker is really asking about the value of the thing, they will usually phrase it differently.

*How good is (something)?* is an open question, asking about how good the thing is for some purpose. It does not typically have a negative slant.

So your first question in practice means "I think it is pointless to believe something", whereas your second is genuinely asking about how good it is to believe the thing  - though it is not clear what you mean by "good": you might be talking about how satisfying it is, or how virtuous it is, or how much you (the speaker) approve of somebody believing it.

Comment: I like this answer. Considering my motive, my choice will be the first sentence.